# How to override a column direction for one element that is a part of column direction flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If i have a flex container with `flex-direction: column`, lets say this container wraps three divs.

My question is: How to make the second div be displayed inline with the first one and still the third has the effect of column direction  without changing this html formula:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

I need to do that without modifying html, is there a way to achieve that by css only??

Answer (score 3):

You either

- put first two divs in a wrapper with `display:flex` (1)
- or change the parent's direction to `row`, give it `flex-wrap:wrap` and give third div `min-width: 100%` (2)

(1)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-container > *:first-child{
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

(2)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-container > *:last-child{
  min-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the CSS [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property to re-arrange items in the container.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-container > div {
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  width: 50px;
}

.flex-container > div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

/* non-essential decorative styles */
.flex-container {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.flex-container > div {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We clearly read the question differently. Admittedly, we should have requested a [mcve] (which was clearly not provided, since their code does not include `flex-direction` - OP only tells a story about it). You assumed the container has a defined height and wraps, which is not obvious to me (the container *"wraps 3 divs"* might simply be a synonym for *"contains"*).

Comment: Hi @AndreiGheorghiu. Actually, I didn't assume anything. I just stuck to the requirements in the question: *"How to make the second div be displayed inline with the first one and still the third has the effect of column direction without changing this html formula.*" If there are other requirements or limitations, the OP should edit the question.

Comment: They never mention a defined height or that `flex-wrap` is set to `wrap`. If OP indeed asked what you think they did, it would have probably been better if they specified any of the two in clear. None is obvious (at least for me).